# When are even symmetric matrices invertible?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse, symmetric-matrices

Let $A$ be a symmetric $n\times n$ real matrix. By even, I mean that
$$i+j \text{ is odd } \Rightarrow A_{ij}=0$$

What can be said about the invertibility of such symmetric even matrices? I would be looking for a characterization of which such matrices are singular and which are non-singular that exploits both the even and symmetric properties of the matrix.

Comment: Surely if you re-order the basis you are just looking at pair of symmetric matrices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By rearranging the rows and columns, we can produce a block-diagonal matrix. For example,
$$
\pmatrix{a_{11}&0&a_{13}&0\\
0 & a_{22} &0 & a_{24}\\
a_{31}&0&a_{33}&0\\
0&a_{42}&0&a_{44}} \to 
%
\pmatrix{a_{11}&a_{13}&0&0\\
0 & 0& a_{22} & a_{24}\\
a_{31}&a_{33}&0&0\\
0&0&a_{42}&a_{44}} \to 
\pmatrix{a_{11}&a_{13}&0&0\\
a_{31}&a_{33}&0&0\\
0 & 0& a_{22} & a_{24}\\
0&0&a_{42}&a_{44}}.
$$
In this case, the first matrix will be invertible if and only if the two matrices
$$
\pmatrix{a_{11} & a_{13}\\ a_{31}&a_{33}}, \quad \pmatrix{a_{22} & a_{24}\\ a_{42} & a_{44}}
$$
are invertible.